# Keeping DB in sync with EF across projects

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am using model-first entity framework (edmx) to connect to my database across about 4 separate projects.

Now, whenever I make a DB change I have to update the edmx for each project. I have considered creating a WCF Data Service, but I would still have to update the service reference in each project.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you able to switch to code-first at all, or are you locked into doing it with model-first?

Comment: @IronMan84 locked in, although I may be able to make an argument for code-first if there is a significantly better way of handling it

Comment: If you were doing code-first all you would have to do is deploy the updated classes to each project and then initialize the database. EF 4.3 introduced the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer so that you can then easily track all of the changes that were made to the databases and at what dates.